# Bootstrap Navbar Doesn't Appear Properly in my Vue js App

Tags: vue.js, navbar

I am trying to add a bootstrap navbar to my Vue js app but am running into some problems. I would really appreciate any help you may offer. Thanks!

I copied the navbar code from bootstrap into my App.vue file but for some reason it doesn't appear on the whole screen.

The navbar appears like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOp1y.png)

And when I inspect it it shows like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUDq3.png)

This is my main.js code:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
// import $ from "jquery";
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
import "popper.js";
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

This is my App.vue code:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#"
              id="navbarDropdown"
              role="button"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input
            class="form-control mr-sm-2"
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search"
          />
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;

  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I can't see the differrnce between expected and actual behaviour on your screenshots. Please describe?

Comment: You might be interested in [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/). It supplies Vue component wrappers for the Bootstrap components and removes the need to include jQuery

Comment: In your screenshot, you have a `<div class="hello">` that doesn't appear in your code above. What styling does `.hello` have? Also, you have styles for `#nav` but no element exists with that ID. This is impossible to debug without a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Phil the class "hello" and #nav were left over from the HelloWorld.vue file that is automatically generated when using creating a Vue project. When I remove them there is no difference.

Comment: @Valdimir Shefer the desired behavior is for the search input field and search button to be one next to each other in the right side of the bootstrap navbar, not on top of each other in the left half of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the problem.

Once I pasted the css Bootstrap link in the head of the index.html, the layout appeared properly:

I also had to paste the jquery and popper cdn links into the head to make the dropdown menu in the navbar work.